# Какой путь создания лог-файла указывать для конфиг-файла log4j2.xml, если у меня веб-проект, запускающийся с Tomcat-а?

Tags: tomcat, log4j

```
<Appenders>
    <File name="log4j2" fileName="????">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c:%L %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Относительный путь относительно рабочего каталога Tomcat, это по крайней мере логично. `${sys:catalina.base}/logs/log_file.log`. А так здесь нет однозначного ответа, каждый пишет туда куда ему удобно и туда, куда согласовано в проекте. Особенно если эти логи какой-то ещё сервис потом будет подтягивать.